# Transforming Linear Gradients Individually For Each Element

Tags: svg, gradient, linear-gradients

Just wanted to double check whether I understand this correctly:

- If I want to use linear gradients on SVG elements, like `<rect>`, I need to first put the `<linearGradient>` inside the `<defs>` and then reference it either in `fill` or in `style`.
- If I want to transform the gradient for each `<rect>` individually, I can't do that without defining a `<linearGradient>` for each individual `<rect>`, since the `gradientTransform` property is only allowed on gradient elements.

I'm just confused because ChatGPT told me I can put `gradientTransform` on my `<rect>` but MDN says

> You can use this attribute with the following SVG elements:
>
> - `<linearGradient>`
> - `<radialGradient>`

So I need individual `<linearGradient>`s for each `<rect>`?

Comment: Your takeaway should be to stop listening to ChatGPT.

Comment: Yes, still I wanted to understand my possibilities here, since it would be really convenient if there was a way to transform the gradients individually without having a ton of `<linearGradient>` elements!

Comment: If you want a different gradient, you'll need to create a different gradient.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot!  Do you want to add this as an answer?

Comment: Also, can I somehow directly specify the gradient on the `<rect>` inline?  Or do I always need to reference a `<linearGradient>` element from the `<defs>`?

Comment: you can create the gradient as a data url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you  will need a different gradient for each transformation. But the SVG gradient elements support [a bit of templating](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/pservers.html#PaintServerTemplates):

> Most paint server elements accept an `href` attribute, which can be used to define a compatible paint server element as a template. Attributes defined for the template element are used instead of the initial value if corresponding attributes are not specified on the current element. Furthermore, if the current element does not have any child content other than descriptive elements, than the child content of the template element is cloned to replace it.

Like this:

```
<linearGradient id="grad0" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
  <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#A8F" />
  <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#FDC" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="grad1" href="grad0" gradientTransform="rotate(30)" />
<linearGradient id="grad2" href="grad0" gradientTransform="rotate(60)" />
```